# How can I aggregate by a category in a column to fill nulls in another column? (python)

Tags: python, group-by, null

Example:

I want to see the mean of salaries of basic education (this column has basic, high school, BSc,...) and  fill the nulls in salaries with this mean, but just for those clients that have the basic education.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Bruna, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please share an example of what you tried and what your data looks like?

Comment: sense['Gross Monthly Salary'] = sense[['Educational Degree'], columns = '1 - Basic'].replace(np.nan, mean())   Thanks for your help